# Instance Variable Definition in Controller Issue: Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

I have a single user table with two roles defined using enums and Single Table Inheritance with two matching user sub classes for Staff and Clinician. Because I need a lot of information about clinicians that I don't need about Staff, I've created a clinician_profiles table and am using after_create :create_clinician_profile in the user model to create a stub for the clinician profile.

I am trying to build a page for clinicians to complete their profiles and am having trouble getting the instance variable defined in the controller so it pulls the appropriate clinician's profile into the view to render the form. I am getting the following error. Note that the user's id I'm logged in as is 104.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ClinicianProfilesController#edit
Couldn't find ClinicianProfile with 'id'=104
```

I feel like I'm close but don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated for a rookie!

I'm landing on the page using this link in the header:

```
<li><%= link_to "Manage My Profile", edit_clinician_profile_path(current_user) %></li>
```

Here are relevant parts of my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :role
  enum role: { Staff: 0, Clinician: 1}
  belongs_to :university
  has_many :referral_requests

class Staff < User
  validates :university_id, presence: true
end

class Clinician < User
  has_many :lists
  has_many :universities, through: :lists
  has_one :clinician_profile
  after_create :create_clinician_profile
end
```

Here's my ClinicianProfile model:

```
class ClinicianProfile < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :clinician_profile_languages
    has_many :languages, through: :clinician_profile_languages
    has_many :clinician_profile_races
    has_many :races, through: :clinician_profile_races
    belongs_to :clinician
end
```

clinician_profiles schema

```
create_table "clinician_profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "address1"
    t.string   "address2"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.boolean  "accepting_patients"
    t.integer  "rate"
    t.string   "license_number"
    t.string   "license_state"
    t.string   "school"
    t.integer  "year_graduated"
    t.string   "accepts_insurance"
    t.boolean  "sliding_scale"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.boolean  "verified"
    t.integer  "years_licensed"
    t.integer  "years_of_experience"
    t.integer  "clinician_id"
  end
```

ClinicianProfilesController

```
class ClinicianProfilesController < ApplicationController
def edit
    @clinician_profile = ClinicianProfile.find(params[:id])
end

def index
end

def show
end

def create
end

end
```

Here's the beginning of my view (edit.html.erb in /views/clinician_profiles)

```
<%= form_for(@clinician_profile) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

Comment: It seems you don't have a ClinicianProfile created with id 104. Check if you're passing the correct params[:id]

Comment: yup isn't your user's id that is 104? (the one you are logged with). The ClinicianProfile belonging to that user might have a different id.

You could get something like: 
`@clinician_profile = current_user.clinician_profile` if you know is "clinician"

Comment: How are landing on the edit view? By clicking a link? If so post that code. Somewhere you are passing wrong `params`

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Pavan I just added the link_to code to my original post.

Comment: rccursach's solution worked. This makes sense and seems totally obvious now that you point it out. I swear I'm getting there... thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
def edit
    @clinician_profile = ClinicianProfile.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to :index and return unless @clinician_profile
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to say here?

Comment: check if @clinician_profile is null then return to index page and not going to edit form.